# Webpack 4 Multiple file types per entry does not output css files

Tags: css, webpack, multipleoutputs, multiple-entries

I have a situation when I have multiple themes in a project and every theme has it's [theme-name].scss file and [theme-name].js file which has to be compiled into [theme-name]/dist folder. So I have multiple entries with multiple outputs.

I thought I've found the simplified solution on Webpack's page here: https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/entry-advanced/ , however only 2 js files are built into dist folder and no css. Maybe someone could tell me why it's so? Thank you.

My exact config:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: {
    home: ['./src/js/home.js', './src/scss/home.scss'],
    account: ['./src/js/account.js', './src/scss/account.scss'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          // fallback to style-loader in development
          process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
        
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css'
    }),
  ],
};
```

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fqin.png)